# How these two lines of code performing exactly the same operation on the javascript object rect?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, arguments

line1:

```
rect.setSize(height,widht)
```

line2:

```
setRectSize(rect,width,height)
```

The hypothetical functions invoked in these two lines of code may perform exactly the same operation on the (hypothetical) object **rect**.but the method invocation syntax in the first lines more clearly indicates the idea that it is the object **rect** that is the primary focus of the operation.

Comment: How? can't tell ... show the definition of them

Comment: I can understand the first line but can't understand the second line .

Comment: the second line calls a function that does things to the passed in `rect`

Comment: Bravo, If you give the code for second line?

Comment: Are maybe using a library that's exposing the second function as an alias to the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Assume `rect` is an instance of an object that has a method like

```
Rect.prototoype.setSize = function (h, w) {
    this.height = h;
    this.width = w;
}

rect.setSize(height, widht);
```

that's the same as doing

```
rect.height = height;
rect.width = widht;
```

Now the function

```
function setSize(rect, width, height) {
    rect.height = height;
    rect.width = width;
}
setSize(rect, width, height);
```

You can see it does the same thing